# get data from combobox

Tags: cakephp, combobox

Hi there i want to get data from the below combo box in cakephp for comparison.

```
echo $form->input('ac_owner', array('label' => 'Account Owner',
                 'options' => array('A','B','C'), 'default' => 2));
```

is it possible to get this value using javascript

please help.
thank you in advance........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this is a normal `<select>` element that can of course be accessed by Javascript. The id, if you're looking for that, should be something along the lines of `ModelNameAcOwner`. Inspect the resulting HTML or DOM tree to find it.